# How to name IP addresses on micro webserver

Tags: webserver, stm32, lwip

I have an stm32H743 micro controller webserver (Cubeide LWIP) which displays a small webpage on my local LAN.
When I look at the router page, I see that all local IP's have a name associated with them.

Ethernet:   COM-MID1    80:c7:55:94:12:14   192.168.1.115
STM32       00:80:e1:01:00:23   192.168.1.75
My question is - how do I change the name 'STM32' in my webserver code?
As you may imagine, there are thousands of references in my source code and I cant find the corresponding one. Where is it likely to be?
Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your router is presenting client host names from [DHCP option 12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132.html#section-3.14)?
With lwIP, you can specify the DHCP client host name by #defining the [LWIP_NETIF_HOSTNAME](https://www.nongnu.org/lwip/2_1_x/group__lwip__opts__netif.html#gaa714dbfa66822ec4c6111bdb8cf753c1) option and then setting the hostname-field in the netif struct.